# How to load image inside HTML Buttons

Tags: android

I have one button inside webview as :

return `INPUT TYPE=\"button\" type = \"image\"  src = \"file:///android_asset//ui_btn_next.png\"  NAME=\"Viewer2\" VALUE=\"Next\" onClick=\"window.Question.OnJsClick_Next()\">";`

I want image inside button. I have that image inside asset folder. How can I access that image inside that button.

I have tried :

Way 1: `return INPUT TYPE=\"button\" type = \"image\"  src = \"file:///android_asset//ui_btn_next.png\"  NAME=\"Viewer2\" VALUE=\"Next\" onClick=\"window.Question.OnJsClick_Next()\">";`

Way 2: `return "<INPUT TYPE=\"button\" type =\"image\" <style> #myImage { background-image: url(\"file:///android_asset/myImage.jpg\"; width: 250px; height: 50px;}\"  VALUE=\"Next\" onClick=\"window.Question.OnJsClick_Next()\">";`

Way3 :return "INPUT TYPE=\"button\" type =\"image\" img src=\"file:///android_res/drawable/btn_next.png VALUE=\"Next\" onClick=\"window.Question.OnJsClick_Next()\">";

But no luck.. Can anyone help me out of this. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one too:

```
<button id="Next"><img src="myimage.jpg"/>Next</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

This a HTML/CSS question.

```
<input type="image" src="images.jpg" value="Next" alt="Next">
```

Should work.

You're setting the "type" attribute several times. Which of course won't work :)